# Karaf Bundle.getState() doesn't exactly match bundle's status in bundle:list

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

how does the karaf client's bundle:list command determine the bundles' states? When a bundle show "Failure" in bundle:list, programmatically running this bundle's getState() (to display on a gui) shows Active. Is there another api i can use to determine if the bundle is in Failure state? Karaf version is 4.1.5 although it shows on earlier versions too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar situation. If you look at the Karaf sources for the bundle:list, you'll notice that they use org.apache.karaf.bundle.core.BundleInfo to get the state via org.apache.karaf.bundle.core.BundleService =>

> org.apache.karaf.bundle.core.BundleInfo info = bundleService.getInfo(bundle.get());
>
> info.getState();

More info: https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/5144a1eba5687dab0f016a9bf95e58e6687a26ad/bundle/core/src/main/java/org/apache/karaf/bundle/command/List.java

Comment: Noticed your answer just now :) Thanks!

Comment: Hi - How did you get the reference to bundleService? I see it's autowired with @Reference but i don't have the library for it. Did you do it another way? Thanks again.